# Help parse XML to PHP by attribute value

Tags: php, xml, xpath

Could someone kindly help me get this parsed. I have the following XML. I need to get the value of `photo-url` that matches "75" `max-width`. How do I filter that in PHP 
`$xml->posts->post['photo-url']`....?

```
<photo-url max-width="100">
image1.jpg
</photo-url>

<photo-url max-width="75">
image2.jpg
</photo-url>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `SimpleXMLElement` and an xpath query.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($your_xml_string);
$result = $xml->xpath('//photo-url[@max-width="75"]');

// Loop over all the <photo-url> nodes and dump their contents
foreach ($result as $node ) {
   print_r($node);
   $image = strip_tags($node->asXML);
}
```

Comment: Woo, thanks! So my final usage was as following `$img = $xml->xpath('//photo-url[@max-width="75"]'); echo '<img src="'.$img[0].'" />';`

Answer (score 4):

Using PHP DOM

```
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadXml('
<root>
    <photo-url max-width="100">image1.jpg</photo-url>
    <photo-url max-width="75">image2.jpg</photo-url>
</root>
');

$xpath = new DomXpath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query('//photo-url[@max-width="75"]') as $photoUrlNode) {
    echo $photoUrlNode->nodeValue; // will be image2.jpg
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use XPath: `//photo-url[@max-width = '75']`. It will select all `photo-url` which satisfies this condition. To select only 1st `photo-url` use this: `//photo-url[@max-width = '75'][1]`