# Trouble reading XML tag attributes with PHP

Tags: php, xml

Given the following

```
<data type="new">
     <time>1</time>
     <time>2</time>
</data>

 <data type="old">
      <time>3</time>
      <time>4</time>
 </data
```

The goal being to type something along the following

```
   <?php 
    $test = simplexml_load_file('http://....')
    echo $test->data['type="old"']->time[0] //I want this to return 3
   ?>
```

and get the value of 3!
I hate tried using attributes but I'm still on the search for the solution.

Thanks,
JTC

The actually doc I'm trying to parse from

```
<data type="current observations">
    <time-layout time-coordinate="local">
        <start-valid-time period-name="current">2013-05-27T13:53:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
    </time-layout>
</data>
```

I attempted the following but got an Invalid expression warning.

```
  $weather = simplexml_load_file('http://...');
  $time=$weather->xpath('//data[@type="current observations"]/"time-layout"/"start-valid-   time"');
  echo $time[0];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help parse XML to PHP by attribute value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763760/help-parse-xml-to-php-by-attribute-value)

Comment: I would agree they are similar but I'm interested in the array value.

Comment: the questions are identical, whether you know it or not.

Comment: They looked similar to my lack of presenting the question better. I have sence updated it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, taking your actual XML document which is well-formed, you could do this...

```php
$data = $weather->xpath('/data[@type="current observations"]');
$time_layout = $data[0]->xpath('time-layout[@time-coordinate="local"]');
$start_valid_time = $time_layout[0]->xpath('start-valid-time[@period-name="current"]');
echo (string)$start_valid_time[0];
```

See it in action [here](http://3v4l.org/LMa8X).

Comment: being that the file is not actually in the document ie I'm pulling the data in. Can i use the simplexml_load_string() just  like the simplexml_load_file()

Comment: You don't need to change that line. We are using different functions for demo purposes only. The line you want is the next one.

Comment: when trying to use your code the [0]->time[0] gave me an error! I also updated the above question to better reflect the problem I'm having.

Comment: Sorry @tman, my original syntax was only working in latest versions of PHP. I've updated with better syntax supported in 5.0.0 upwards. You can see [here](http://3v4l.org/LMa8X).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [code snippet](http://codepad.org/rxFkfRBP) using SimpleXMLElement and XPath. I've added a root `datas` node so the XML could be parsed, I'm guessing yours is well formed.

```
<?php
$xml = <<<XML
<datas>
    <data type="new">
        <time>1</time>
        <time>2</time>
    </data>
    <data type="old">
        <time>3</time>
        <time>4</time>
    </data>
</datas>
XML;

$sxe  = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$time = $sxe->xpath('//data[@type="old"]/time');
echo $time[0];
```

#### Output

```
3
```

Comment: the XML file is located external to the file that's why i was using simplexml_load_file() im not sure of how to use the impleXMLElement()

Comment: Read the official documentation of [SimpleXMLElement _construct](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.construct.php), you'll notice that it accepts external URLs and local paths. Just do something like `$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement('http://....', 0, true);`.

Comment: I updated the bottom of my question to better reflect my problem! I tried your suggestion with no luck but this may due to my highly lacking knowledge of parsing.